# Twitter - find "friends" who also use the current app

Tags: twitter

I am looking for a **twitter equivalent** for the facebook api call to find friends who use the same app:

```
FB.api({
            method: 'fql.multiquery',
            access_token : accessToken,
            queries: {
                query1: 'SELECT uid, name, is_app_user FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) AND is_app_user=1',
                query2: 'SELECT id, name, url, pic FROM profile WHERE id IN (SELECT uid FROM #query1)'
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no Twitter equivalent to this.  The only view you have into what applications another Twitter use has is the "source" field in the individual tweets.  There's no way in the documented API to determine if a particular user is using a particular app.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i guess i have to handle this by finding all friends and find the intersection with the user specific twitter id of my custom platform.